# Use of ceramics in internal combustion engines - why and why not?

Tags: ceramics

I have a question concerning if there is any automobile company that has mass 
produced ceramic engines?

If not then why is that?

I have tried searching but couldn't come up with any answers.

Answer (score 2):

A search gives many links, such as Ford using zirconia ceramics and aircraft manufacturers using ceramics to increase the turbine inlet temperature : images and sources below:

Source : http://ceramicrotaryengines.com
[image]

Source : http://www.substech.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=ceramics_in_combustion_engines

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of anyone who's done this. Ceramic components certainly, but not an entire engine. A significant issue is tensile strength - while compressive strength is excellent with ceramic materials, tensile strength is not.

A ceramic liner for a piston - where it would be surrounded by a metal with high tensile strength and would be operating exclusively in compression - would be a good idea. A ceramic block to contain repeated compression and expansion would be more susceptible to fracture.

Comment: A definite difference between the question in the title and that in the body....

Comment: Anyone able to clarify what it was about my answer they didn't like? I'm happy to edit if it'll help.

Comment: I think your answer provided good technical points so +1 from me

Answer (score 2):

From my research, no-one is mass producing complete internal combustion engines. Trials of a reciprocating ceramic engine components were conducted by the [Ford Motor Company](http://www.ultrahardmaterials.co.uk/engine.html), in the USA.

> During the 1980s, in a development program at Ford Motor Company, zirconia-based ceramic components (e.g. a short ceramic cylinder liner) have been successfully tested in reciprocating internal combustion engines for over 500 hours of operation before failure. It was believed that the failure of zirconia ceramic components in internal combustion engines was due to the use of Yttria (Y-TZP) and Magnesia (Mg-TZP) zirconias. These zirconia ceramics are prone to hydrothermal degradation due partly to the moisture present in the fuels (see W.Bunk and H.Hausner "Ceramic Materials and Components for Engines" Proceedings of the Second International Symposium; 14-17 April 1986, Lubeck-Travemunde, FRG). It is believed that these programs were abandoned mainly because of the hydrothermal degradation of the zirconias they used.

Answer (score -1):

an engine block, for example, must resist both compressive loads and tensile loads. Ceramics are at a disadvantage compared to metals in this regard because they exhibit brittle failure in tension.

Comment: A repeat of the answer above with nothing new.